16 Worldview Questions For Buddhists
Good evening, everyone! I'm curious about the Buddhist worldview and would like answers to these sixteen worldview questions. I rely heavily on James W. Sire's worldview questions from his book The Universe Next Door. If anyone is interested and willing, I could also gather your answers to these questions over Zoom or Microsoft Teams. There would be no proselytizing on my end. I'm simply curious. Many thanks for considering my request!

What is prime reality?
What is the nature of external reality, i.e., the world around us?
Are there absolute truths? If so, what is its source?
What is Good, and does it have a source?
What is Evil, and does it have a source?
Where did the universe come from?
What is a human being?
Why or how is it possible to know anything at all?
What is the meaning of human history?
What is the human problem?
What is the purpose of life?
What is the significance of the integration of iconography within Buddhism?
How do we know what is right and wrong?
Are right and wrong, good and evil, absolute concepts?
What happens to a person at death?
Will the universe as we know it come to an end? If so, how and why?


In theory we allow may allow very broad questions, on the understanding that they may get very shallow answers -- e.g. someone could try to reply to each of these 16 questions with a one- or two-sentence answer for each and/or perhaps with a hyperlink. Or they might try to answer one.

Some of the jargon in the question is difficult i.e. unknown or new to me, I can only guess at what it's asking -- e.g. "prime" reality and "absolute" truth. If they have any specific meaning to you, then you might want to define/explain them, otherwise someone's answer might not address what you were asking.

@ChrisW OK. Then I'll reopen it.

I mean, I can answer many from above with Buddhist knowledge. But I would have to write a whole book for that purpose here. So I can't post an answer. Like, assume 100 words for one question and one would have to write 1600 words here, if not more. I would advise on reading some good Buddhist books or post one question at a time. Yet I would love to answer.

@Pycm, thank you for your willingness to engage! I’ll post some of the questions above one at a time, so keep an eye out.

Ok. But be sure to explain what is your question clearly. Otherwise as the frist answer here, answering person has to deal with excavating what the actual question is reading very short question. One word may have different meaning in different contexts. But don't over explain ether. Human languages are very vague. .

As others said, this question is definitely too broad! It is unfortunate that it has received some answers, making closing it problematic on the ground of being unfair to other would-be answerers. I support the idea of taking it apart and posting individual questions.

@AndriyVolkov, I'll work on making individual posts from the questions above. I haven't gotten around to it yet because I've been quite busy as a full-time graduate student.

@AndriyVolkov If you wanted to, I think it would also be tolerated, for you to answer any one of these questions instead of all of them.

@ChrisW Don't want to be negative but OP questions, you not understanding them is as simple as you not knowing the definition of the words he is using. These are pretty common philosophical terms in philosophy/metaphysics. Just use a dictionary for the definition of the words, prime, absolute and reality and you will understand what he is saying.  That being said I think the question(s) is too broad. If I tried answer these questions correctly my reply would be the length of an essay.

@Remyla I don't think you can easily understand Buddhist terms from a dictionary, so I don't presume I can learn philosophical terms that way. Also I'm not here to learn philosophy/metaphysics, and really don't much want to, not that I didn't try a little by myself when I was younger. I'll try to explain things in "plain English" if you're willing, otherwise the question is beyond me.

ChrisW, as @Remyla pointed out, yes, these are somewhat standard philosophical terms that I assumed most people would understand or get the jist of. I apologize if they're confusing, and I'll work on rephrasing them so that more concise answers can be given. I just haven't had much time lately as I'm a full-time graduate student. I'm thankful for the engagement this post has had thus far.


What is prime reality?

The All (the six senses and everything sensed by the six senses) as stated in SN 35.23. Please also read Why are these called "The All"?.

What is the nature of external reality, i.e., the world around us?

It exists and it's impermanent, but we sense it and construct a mental reality out of it, as stated in SN 12.44. Please also read What is world (loka) in SN 12.44? Why is it called "world"?.

Are there absolute truths? If so, what is its source?

The three marks of existence, as stated in AN 3.136.

What is Good, and does it have a source?
What is Evil, and does it have a source?

Evil are the three poisons of passion, aversion, delusion, and good is the opposite of it. See AN 3.69. Please also read What are the three poisons?.

Where did the universe come from?

This is not a practical question from a soteriological perspective.
It's an unconjecturable. See AN 4.77. Also useful is the Parable of the Poisoned Arrow (MN 63).

What is a human being?

A being is defined in SN 23.2 and SN 5.10. A person is defined in SN 22.22.

Why or how is it possible to know anything at all?
What is the meaning of human history?

These are not practical questions from a soteriological perspective. Please see the Parable of the Poisoned Arrow (MN 63).

What is the human problem?
What is the purpose of life?

The four noble truths and noble eightfold path are explained in SN 56.11.

What is the significance of the integration of iconography within Buddhism?

The purpose of a stupa (and other iconography) is to inspire the mind (DN 16).

How do we know what is right and wrong?

It's based on the Golden Rule in Ud 5.1.

Are right and wrong, good and evil, absolute concepts?

The five precepts from AN 8.39 is the absolute minimum set of precepts. Anything more is relative to the definition of good and evil above (i.e. the three poisons).
In general, it is expected that the monks and nuns (as professional practitioners) should aspire towards perfection of virtue, while it is less so for the laity. Please also read this answer.

What happens to a person at death?

This question is not so important based on the understanding gained from SN 22.85.

Will the universe as we know it come to an end? If so, how and why?

This is not a practical question from a soteriological perspective.
It's an unconjecturable. See AN 4.77. Also useful is the Parable of the Poisoned Arrow (MN 63).

Thank you for your thoughts!

What is prime reality?
This isn't a conventional English-language question, I don't understand the question.
If "prime reality" is specialist jargon, e.g. a Christian or a Philosophical technical term, perhaps Buddhist doctrine has no exact equivalent definition/concept/word.
What is the nature of external reality, i.e., the world around us?
This suggests three answers:

Its "nature" is that it's "impermanent" etc:

In Buddhism, the three marks of existence are three characteristics (Pali: tilakkhaṇa; Sanskrit: त्रिलक्षण trilakṣaṇa) of all existence and beings, namely anicca (impermanence), dukkha (commonly translated as "suffering", "unsatisfactory," "unease"), and anattā (without a lasting essence). That humans are subject to delusion about the three marks, that this delusion results in suffering, and that removal of that delusion results in the end of dukkha, is a central theme in the Buddhist Four Noble Truths and Noble Eightfold Path.


Its "condition" (requisite) is "contact":

Sparśa (Sanskrit; Pali: phassa) is a Sanskrit/Indian term that is translated as "contact", "touching", "sensation", "sense impression", etc. It is defined as the coming together of three factors: the sense organ, the sense object, and sense consciousness (vijnana). For example, contact (sparsha) is said to occur at the coming together of the eye organ, a visual object, and the visual sense consciousness.


To the extent that it's defined by one's attitude towards it:

Four sublime states of mind have been taught by the Buddha

Love or Loving-kindness (metta)
Compassion (karuna)
Sympathetic Joy (mudita)
Equanimity (upekkha)

In Pali, the language of the Buddhist scriptures, these four are known under the name of Brahma-vihara. This term may be rendered by: excellent, lofty or sublime states of mind; or alternatively, by: Brahma-like, god-like or divine abodes.
These four attitudes are said to be excellent or sublime because they are the right or ideal way of conduct towards living beings (sattesu samma patipatti). They provide, in fact, the answer to all situations arising from social contact.



Are there absolute truths? If so, what is its source?
As with the question about "prime" reality, I'm not sure what you mean when you ask about "absolute" truth.
What is Good, and does it have a source? What is Evil, and does it have a source?
Maybe this:

The three poisons (Sanskrit: triviṣa; Tibetan: dug gsum) in the Mahayana tradition or the three unwholesome roots (Sanskrit: akuśala-mūla; Pāli: akusala-mūla), in the Theravada tradition are a Buddhist term that refers to the three root kleshas that lead to all negative states. These three states are delusion, also known as ignorance, greed or sensual attachment, and hatred or aversion. These three poisons are considered to be three afflictions or character flaws that are innate in beings and the root of craving, and so causing suffering, pain or unsatisfactoriness and rebirth.

Conversely from ibid.

The three wholesome mental factors that are identified as the opposites of the three poisons are:

amoha (non-delusion) or paññā (wisdom)
alobha (non-attachment) or dāna (generosity)
adveṣa (non-hatred) or mettā (loving-kindness)

Buddhist path considers these essential for liberation.

Where did the universe come from?
This might be one of "The unanswerable questions" i.e. questions which the Buddha declined to "take a position" on.
What is a human being?
I guess it's a type of sentient being i.e. a being composed of the five aggregates and more specifically not some other type of sentient being e.g. "animal" or "deva" etc.
Why or how is it possible to know anything at all?
What a question.
One answer, from the Kalama sutta is that there are things which you "know for yourselves" to be true, and which are "approved by the wise".

"Come, Kalamas. Do not go upon what has been acquired by repeated hearing; nor upon tradition; nor upon rumor; nor upon what is in a scripture; nor upon surmise; nor upon an axiom; nor upon specious reasoning; nor upon a bias towards a notion that has been pondered over; nor upon another's seeming ability; nor upon the consideration, 'The monk is our teacher.' Kalamas, when you yourselves know: 'These things are good; these things are not blamable; these things are praised by the wise; undertaken and observed, these things lead to benefit and happiness,' enter on and abide in them.

What is the meaning of human history?
n/a
What is the human problem?
This answer suggested that different schools of Buddhist identify different problems as "fundamental".
What is the purpose of life?
To the extent that "purpose" and "intention" are synonyms, perhaps different people have different "intentions".
What is the significance of the integration of iconography within Buddhism?
Perhaps this should be a separate question.
I believe it wasn't introduced during the Buddha's lifetime.
Perhaps it's to "signify" Buddhism -- which might also be summarized as or by the recollections.
How do we know what is right and wrong?
See the questions above -- "what are good and evil?" and "how is it possible to know anything at all"?
Are right and wrong, good and evil, absolute concepts?
I guess it's that "actions (incl. intentions) have consequences" etc.
What happens to a person at death?
They die, don't they?
That "person" ceases to be, in some conventional sense -- their body decomposes or is burned, their property is dispersed -- though of course they also "live on" in memory and perhaps in other ways.
The question of what happens after death is or isn't answered in more or less detail by various schools of Buddhism.
This may be an unwise question to ask, related to "identity view" -- see also A thicket of wrong views
Will the universe as we know it come to an end? If so, how and why?
An obvious answer might be that everything within the universe is impermanent etc. -- "everything that has a beginning has an end". Things "arise" when the conditions for their becoming arise, and cease when their conditions cease to be.
I'm not sure I understand the question, if you're asking about a "universe" that's somehow distinct from everything that's in it.

Thank you for your thoughtful answers, Chris!

I think the list of 16 questions can be broadly categorised into a few areas. Questions 1, 2, 3, 6 and 16 are all related to reality and the nature of the universe. Questions 4, 5, 11, 13, 14 and 15 are related to morality, standards for right and wrong and thus the purpose of existence. Questions 7, 8, 9 and 10 relate to the limitations (conversely, the potential) of human existence. I will skip question 12 as I am not very sure what is being asked.
Thus, I will answer the questions as 3 broad categories.
Reality and the nature of the universe
I believe there is something both science and Buddhism agreed to be of vital importance when explaining how things come to be i.e. the concept of causality/conditionality. In Buddhism, causality/conditionality is the core principal behind dependent origination.

if this exists, that exists; if this ceases to exist, that also ceases to exist

It is also the reason why karma existed. In science, causality is what allows us to infer forward (for example, our sun will turn into a white dwarf, billions of years from now) and backward (our universe began with a big bang). Causality explains how things evolved whether it is the celestial bodies or human bodies.
So, if we understand causality/conditionality, we begin to understand what reality is, its nature and how it is in a constant state of evolution, change and flux. And everything eventually perishes (even the universe) and in its place something new arises (perhaps, another universe?).
morality, standards for right and wrong and thus the purpose of existence
The causality/conditionality that underpins reality meant that what is good and evil is relative and subjected to change. A bacon is good for a human but evil to a pig. This inherent relativity and subjectivity drive many thinkers (since antiquity) to question the purpose of existence. If I am the last dinosaur in my herd about to die of starvation because a large asteroid struck earth a couple of weeks ago; does it matter what is the purpose of life? Perhaps, there is none, only despair.
Fast forward to modern times, a human like me is grateful to the meteorite for removing the earth of dinosaurs and allowing homo-sapiens to emerge. Therefore, as a Buddhist, death is a continuation as far as my understanding goes.

The world is without ownership. One has to pass on, leaving everything behind

It is a continuation that Ven. Ratthapala stressed only involving our karma (MN82); all our worldly possessions, memories, likes and dislikes, beliefs, principles and so on are left behind.
the limitations (conversely, the potential) of human existence
Causality/conditionality does not mean that we are passive recipients of effects arising from the interplay of causes and conditions. Buddhism teaches us that we can be an active player shaping the causes and conditions to a better future for ourselves and those around. This knowledge alone is better than knowing how the universe began and how it’ll end. Because we are shaping our destiny as a species and our lives as individuals which is far more enriching and fulfilling.

Thank you for your answers, Desmon!

Frist read this article > Read : The Fourteen Questions to Which Buddha Remained Silent : The Theravada Version
.
Buddha didn't want to answer some questions, not because he didn't knew. But because(could be) ,

it wouldn't help to reach Nirvana,
it would make speculations in the future,
it wouldn't be able to understand with human languages.



All answers are based on Theravada buddhist ideology and my personal understanding of it.
Be aware, Someone reading this answer without proper knowledge or understanding of Buddhist views may lose faith in Buddhism.

1) What is prime reality?
Part 1) Objects
There are only two parts(objective) in the universe.

Mind / conciseness
Matter

In the universe, matter is created by the mind.
For all past eternity, mind existed ; so matter existed. One form or another. (matter).
Part 2) Laws

There are some absolute truths in the universe ; around above Mind and Matter.
(universal laws).
cause and effect

Neither Mind or Matter are static.(not static means, not keep their form continue). But rather they are(both) dynamic.
Which means is, the basic building blocks of both Mind and Matter are,

Get born / popping up
Stay (evolve)
Die / destroy

.
Popping up don't just happen for no reason. They happen according to the cause and effect.(at very high speed / frequency).

2) What is the nature of external reality, i.e., the world around us?
Physical reality (matter) is made up of Rupakalapa(Ashtaka rupakalapa, Shuddashtaka).
This Shuddashtaka is the basic building block of all the matter in the universe.
This Shuddashtaka get born, stay(evolve), die/destroy.
So they are not static ; but dynamic. (like popping up and disappearing).
This is a very big topic ; so I stop here.

3) Are there absolute truths? If so, what is its source?

Are there absolute truths?

Yes.

what is its source?

The mind.
(don't expect to explain it. Because it's what was asked, that why short answers.)

4) What is Good, and does it have a source?

What is Good


At the absolute level/momentary level , good is what satisfy the mind. (I mean it's good for him/her, whatever is the effects are on others).

at the scale of time, good is things what gives people happiness (happy results from doing something).



does it have a source?

Yes.
The mind.

5) What is Evil, and does it have a source?
Exactly as the above answer but opposite.

6) Where did the universe come from?
It was eternal, and now it exists and will exist for future eternity.(not the bigbang universe, but whole universe; off topic, so I stop here).
That's only because mind existed all past eternity and will for future eternity.
Universe will only exist until mind exists.

7) What is a human being?
Just a living being with conciseness from 31 planes(human form is one from 31) of existence of conciseness.

15) What happens to a person at death?
Mind /conciseness has three (3) states.

popping up / beginning
Stay / evolve
Dissappear / end

This is the cycle.
This cycle has very big frequency.(example : like more cycles than 1000000000per second)
So, at the death, conciseness completes last cycle in last(dieing body) body. Next popping up happens in new body.(rebirth body).
Then cycles continue in this new body.
Then there's no conciseness in last(old) body. So it just decompose. We / humans / relatives of last life call this death of a person.

16) Will the universe as we know it come to an end? If so, how and why?

Will the universe as we know it come to an end?

Yes.

If so, how and why?

how
There are multiple levels.

end of the humans on this Earth
end of the Earth
end of the this planetary system including all 31 planes
end of the all

why
That's because it's the nature of the universe. It began, stay (evolve), destroy.
It's the nature of everything, the mind, matter. (which make up the world / universe).
Thanks . ☸️.
Questions are welcome.

Thank you for contributing to the conversation!
